# Show that $\frac{\cos^2(n)}{1+n^2}$ is not decreasing.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, real-numbers

Let $a_n=\frac{\cos^2(n)}{1+n^2}$.  I want to show that the sequence $(a_n)_n$ never becomes decreasing, i.e, if $b^k_n=a_{n+k}$, then, the sequence $(b^k_n)_n$ is not decreasing for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Although we have the cosine function oscilating there, it is easy to see that we can construct decreasing sequences out of $f(x)=\frac{\cos^2(x)}{1+x^2}$. It seems like the sets $A=\{x\in\mathbb{R}\,|\,f(x)>f(x+1)\}$ and $A^c$ both have infinite intersection with $\mathbb{N}$, and that would be sufficient to show what i want, but i don't know how to prove that. any tips will be aprecciated.

Comment: $cos^2(\frac{(2m+1)\pi}{2})=0$.  Show that for an infinite no. of n's, there are values of  $m$ close enough.

Comment: Try looking at signs of the derivative of $f(x) = \cos^2(x)/(1+x^2)$ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to show that

$${\cos^2n\over1+n^2}-{\cos^2(n+1)\over1+(n+1)^2}$$

is infinitely often negative, it suffices to show the same for

$$(1+n^2)(\cos^2n-\cos^2(n+1))+(2n+1)\cos^2n$$

Note that

$$\begin{align}
\cos^2n-\cos^2(n+1)
&=\cos^2n-(\cos n\cos1-\sin n\sin1)^2\\
&=\cos^2n(1-\cos^21)+2\cos n\sin n\cos1\sin1-\sin^2n\sin^21\\
&=\cos^2n\sin^21+\sin2n\cos1\sin1-\sin^2n\sin^21\\
&=(\cos2n\sin1+\sin2n\cos1)\sin1\\
&=\sin(2n+1)\sin1
\end{align}$$

So we need to show that

$$(1+n^2)\sin(2n+1)\sin1+(2n+1)\cos^2n$$

is infinitely often negative.

Since $2\pi/3\gt2$, it happens that $2n+1\in(7\pi/6,11\pi/6)$ mod $2\pi$ for infinitely many $n$, and for each such $n$, we have  $\sin(2n+1)\lt-1/2$. And since $\sin1\gt0$, we have $(n^2+1)\sin1\gt2(2n+1)$ for all sufficiently large $n$. It follows that

$$(1+n^2)\sin(2n+1)\sin1+(2n+1)\cos^2n$$

is negative for infinitely many $n$, and we're done.

(My thanks to the OP for pointing out a mistake in the original answer.)

Comment: Thanks Barry, but as in  the second inequality should go $\cos^2 n$ instead of $\cos n$, we have to refine your last argument, since the second term in the last inequality is now positive.

Comment: @Alan, yikes, you're right. I'll see if I can fix it.

Comment: @Alan, fixed now. Thank you again for pointing out the error.

Answer (score 1):

Find an $n$ such that $n$ is within $\varepsilon$ of $\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi$ for some integer $k$, where $\varepsilon$ is, say, $0.01$. You can do this because when you reduce integers mod $2\pi$, an irrational number, into $[0,2\pi)$, the set is dense.

This tells you $\cos(n)$ is within $\varepsilon$ of $0$. Then $a_n=\frac{\cos^2(n)}{1+n^2}<\frac{\varepsilon^2}{1+n^2}$.

Meanwhile $n+1$ is within $\varepsilon$ of $\frac{\pi}{2}+1+k\pi$ for some integer $k$. This tells you $\left\lvert\cos(n+1)\right\rvert$ is roughly $\left\lvert\cos(\pi/2+1)\right\rvert$, but certainly greater than $\cos(1)$.

[image]

So $a_{n+1}>\frac{\cos(1)^2}{1+(n+1)^2}$.

Now is $\frac{\cos(1)^2}{1+(n+1)^2}>\frac{\varepsilon^2}{1+n^2}$? That is equivalent to $$\left(\cos^2(1)-\varepsilon^2\right)n^2-\varepsilon^2n +\cos^2(1)-2\varepsilon^2>0$$
For a fixed small $\varepsilon$, this is quadratic in $n$. So there are infinitely many $n$ that satisfy this inequality and are also within $\varepsilon$ of $\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi$.

So we can always find $n$ where $a_{n+1}>a_n$.

Comment: The "problem" here is that it isn't that clear at once that there exist such values of natural $\;n\;$ so close to those irrational values...Without this there is not way to advance.

Comment: @DonAntonio Yes I am assuming one knows that. Since $\pi$ is irrational, integer values reduced mod $2\pi$ are dense in $[0,2\pi)$. If someone does not know that, maybe they don't even know the definition of dense, and I don't want to write a book about it here.

Answer (score 0):

Define

$$f(x):=\frac{\cos^2x}{1+x^2}\implies f'(x)=\frac{-\sin2x\cdot(1+x^2)-2x\cos^2x}{(1+x^2)^2}¿$$

$$=-\frac{(1+x^2)\sin2x+2x(\cos 2x+1)}{(1+x^2)^2}$$

Now, the above is negative (and thus $\;f\;$ is monotone descending) iff

$$(1+x^2)\sin2x+2x\cos 2x +2x>0\;,\;\;x>0$$

and it's easy to see this is false, for example: for $\;x_0=4,000,003\cdot\cfrac\pi4\;$, we get

$$(1+x_0^2)\cdot(-1)+0+2x_0=-x_0^2+2x_0-1=-(x_0-1)^2<0$$

and of course the above happens infinite times...

Comment: The iff only applies to "is negative" but not to "$a_n$ is monotone decreasing". See $a_n=\cos(2\pi n)/n$.

Comment: @Its_me It is the same in that case: $$g(x)=\frac1x=\frac{\cos2\pi x}x\implies f'(x)\frac{-2\pi x\sin2n\pi x-\cos2\pi x}{x^2}$$

and for $\;x\in\Bbb N\;$ the above means $\;f'(n)=\cfrac{0-1}{n^2}=-\cfrac1{n^2}<0\;$ ...

Comment: You changed your statement from $x>0$ to $x\in\mathbb{N}$. But also the new statement doesn't allow a iff for "$a_n$ is monotone decreasing". See $a_n = \cos(2\pi n)/n+nint(n)$, where $nint$ denotes rounding to nearest integer or take any other function of $n$ (not linear) with zero slope at the integers.

Comment: @Its_me I didn't change anything: I just applied to the given data!, which can be put in form of a function, basic use of elementary calculus and etc. If the floor function was fivent then something else should be done as that function isn't differentiable...

Comment: @Its_me Well, I se it is useless to try to explain you. Have a nice day.

Comment: You get me wrong, I really want to understand. I would be happy if you point out my mistake related to the logic:

We have
($f'(x)<0$ for all $x>0$) $\Leftrightarrow$ ($f(x)$ is monotone descending) $\Rightarrow$ ($f(n)$ is monotone descending).

But, because ($f(n)$ is monotone descending) does not imply ($f(x)$ is monotone descending), also $\neg(f(x)$ is monotone descending) does not imply $\neg(f(n)$ is monotone descending). 

Then, $\neg$($f'(x)<0$ for all $x>0$) $\Leftrightarrow$ $\neg(f(x)$ is monotone descending), but this does not imply $ \neg$($f(n)$ is monotone descending).